# “Realm context not found. Did you call useRealm() within a <RealmProvider/>?”

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to configure Realm on my React Native app.
This is my initial component where I am using RealmProvider:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const defaultPathLocalRealm = createRealmContext({
   schema: [Profile]
});

const {RealmProvider} = defaultPathLocalRealm;


function App(): JSX.Element {

 return (

 <AppProvider id={'testmongo-lvvnx'}>
  <UserProvider fallback={Login}>
        <RealmProvider sync={{flexible: true, onError: console.error}}>
          <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator>
                  <Stack.Screen name='SplashScreen' component={SplashScreen}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name='ProfileScreen' component={ProfileScreen}/>
              </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </RealmProvider>
  </UserProvider>
 </AppProvider>

 );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that I get the error below when I call `useRealm()` on `ProfileScreen`:

> Realm context not found. Did you call useRealm() within a ?

This is `ProfileScreen`:

```
const ProfileScreen = () => {
const realm = useRealm()

const app = useApp()

const save = async () => {
    try {

        realm.write(() => {
          const res = realm.create('Profile', {_id: 'klsdfds7fsdfhgfhfg8ysdfh', name: 'Besart', email: "besart.haxhidema@gmail.com"})

          console.log(res)
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
}

const logout = () => {
    app.currentUser?.logOut()
}

return(
    <View>
        <Button onPress={save} title="Save"/>

        <Button onPress={logout} title="Logout"/>
    </View>
 )
}

export default ProfileScreen
```

This is `Profile` schema:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

export class Profile extends Realm.Object<Profile>{
   _id!: string;
   name!: string;
   email?: string;

   static schema = {
       name: 'Profile',
       properties: {
           _id: 'string',
           name: 'string',
           email: 'string'
       },
       primaryKey: '_id'
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you solve your problem - https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/6013#issuecomment-1655687135

> @MinisX You must use the useQuery that was returned from createRealmContext in your application.
> Another option would be to omit createRealmContext and instead import the RealmProvider from `@realm/react` and implement it as so: `<RealmProvider schemas={[Person]}>`
> There is a default `RealmContext` already instantiated in `@realm/react`, so you only really need to call createRealmContext if you are creating multiple Realms.
> We will be updating the documentation soon to reflect this method if using Realm.